# Loading separate components from textfile in swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, variables, text-files

I'm trying to assign four different variables from a textfile.
But the problem is - it just loads as one piece into every single variable.

Here is my code

```
class QuestionMark
{

var Question = text.componentsSeparatedByString(">>")
var Contents = text.componentsSeparatedByString("--")
var option1 = text.componentsSeparatedByString("[")
var option2 = text.componentsSeparatedByString("]")

init(Question: [String], Contents: [String], option1: [String], option2: [String])
{
    self.Question = Question
    self.Contents = Contents
    self.option1 = option1
    self.option2 = option2
}
```

And here is the text file i'm using

```
>>Here is the grocery question
--Apples
--Oranges
[pickApples]pickOranges
```

What am i possibly doing wrong?

Appreciate any insights!

Comment: You call componentsSeparatedByString() on the *same* string with different separators. Are you aware what that function does?

Comment: I'm still learning. I suppose i need to apply this function on separate strings. But how do i do that?

Comment: First split the string into several lines, then go through each line one by one. Depending on the first characters, you can assign it to one of your variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, Swift doesn't make string parsing any more comfortable. Here is something to get you started. The below code will split the input string on newlines, iterate through the result and read the different components into optionals based on the prefix of each line.

```
let text = ">>Here is the grocery question\n--Apples\n--Oranges\n[pickApples]pickOranges"
let lines = split(text) { $0 == "\n" }

var question: String?
var contents: [String]?
var option1: String?
var option2: String?

for line in lines {
    if line.hasPrefix(">>") {
        question = line.substringFromIndex(advance(line.startIndex, 2))
    } else if line.hasPrefix("--") {
        if contents == nil {
            contents = [String]()
        }
        contents?.append(line.substringFromIndex(advance(line.startIndex, 2)))
    } else if line.hasPrefix("[") {
        if let index = line.rangeOfString("]")?.startIndex {
            option1 = line.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(
                start: advance(line.startIndex, 1), end: index))
            option2 = line.substringWithRange(Range<String.Index>(
                start: advance(index, 1), end: line.endIndex))
        }
    }
}

println(question!)
println(contents!)
println(option1!)
println(option2!)
```

The above snippet will print out

```
Here is the grocery question
[Apples, Oranges]
pickApples
pickOranges
```

Comment: @DavidRobertson What do you mean? It doesn't compile or it doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: I'm using this code in a custom cell class for a model - and for it to compile i need to create a function inside a class. this is good code and seems like it works, but out of context. the issue is i can't append my custom cell labels with data from those arrays (( don't know how to mange that

Comment: In the above code only `contents` is an array while the other variables (`question`, `option1` and `option2`) are optional strings. You can set these directly to the label's `text` property.

Comment: tried the code again, it works smoothly, but returns only the last value. I wanted it to be an array that collects all the values from the text string.

Comment: @DavidRobertson What do you mean by last value? Are you trying to parse a file with multiple lines of the form posted in your question?

Comment: @DavidRobertson Maybe it's worth updating your question with the code you have now.